# Making a header file of the Boost::Asio chat_server example gives me "one or multiple defined symbols found" error

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, header, boost-asio

I am new to c++ and boost library, trying to learn a header file by making three separate files from this example. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp
chat_message.hpp is here although I don't think this causes a problem. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_message.hpp

The goal is to slit the example into three components.

1. main.cpp
2. chat_server.h - header file for declaration
3. chat_server.cpp - implementation

Here is my implementation, but I am getting two errors.

0. Error List -

```
LNK1169 > One or more multiple defined symbols found > File-> main.exe
LNK2005 > $dummy_return@asio@boost@@YAXXZ) already defined in chat_server.obj > file-> main.obj
```

Output

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl boost::asio::dummy_return<void>(void)" (??$dummy_return@X@asio@boost@@YAXXZ) already defined in chat_server.obj
1>C:\Users\Offline User\source\repos\main\Debug\main.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "main.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The example code runs fine before splitting into three.
I don't know if it's something to do with typedef or virtual because the other classes and methods are pretty straight forward for me to understand (from what I learned online). Please help me out here and let me know what I am missing here?? Thanks.

1. main.cpp

```
#include "chat_server.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: chat_server <port> [<port> ...]\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        std::list<chat_server> servers;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), std::atoi(argv[i]));
            servers.emplace_back(io_context, endpoint);
        }

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

2. chat_server.h

```
#ifndef CHAT_SERVER_H
#define CHAT_SERVER_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "chat_message.hpp"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef std::deque<chat_message> chat_message_queue;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_participant
{
public:
    virtual ~chat_participant() {};
    virtual void deliver(const chat_message& msg) = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<chat_participant> chat_participant_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_room
{
public:
    void join(chat_participant_ptr participant);

    void leave(chat_participant_ptr participant);

    void deliver(const chat_message& msg);

private:
    std::set<chat_participant_ptr> participants_;
    enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
    chat_message_queue recent_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_session
    : public chat_participant,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
public:
    chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room);

    void start();

    void deliver(const chat_message& msg);

private:
    void do_read_header();

    void do_read_body();

    void do_write();

    tcp::socket socket_;
    chat_room& room_;
    chat_message read_msg_;
    chat_message_queue write_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_server
{
public:
    chat_server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
        const tcp::endpoint& endpoint);
private:
    void do_accept();

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    chat_room room_;
};

#endif
```

3. chat_server.cpp

```
#include "chat_server.h"


void chat_room::join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
{
    participants_.insert(participant);
    for (auto msg : recent_msgs_)
        participant->deliver(msg);
}

void chat_room::leave(chat_participant_ptr participant)
{
    participants_.erase(participant);
}

void chat_room::deliver(const chat_message& msg)
{
    recent_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    while (recent_msgs_.size() > max_recent_msgs)
        recent_msgs_.pop_front();

    for (auto participant : participants_)
        participant->deliver(msg);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
chat_session::chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room)
    : socket_(std::move(socket)),
    room_(room)
{
}

void chat_session::start()
{
    room_.join(shared_from_this());
    do_read_header();
}

void chat_session::deliver(const chat_message& msg)
{
    bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    if (!write_in_progress)
    {
        do_write();
    }
}

void chat_session::do_read_header()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
            if (!ec && read_msg_.decode_header())
            {
                do_read_body();
            }
            else
            {
                room_.leave(shared_from_this());
            }
        });
}

void chat_session::do_read_body()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                room_.deliver(read_msg_);
                do_read_header();
            }
            else
            {
                room_.leave(shared_from_this());
            }
        });
}

void chat_session::do_write()
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
            write_msgs_.front().length()),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                write_msgs_.pop_front();
                if (!write_msgs_.empty())
                {
                    do_write();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                room_.leave(shared_from_this());
            }
        });
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
chat_server::chat_server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
    const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
    : acceptor_(io_context, endpoint)
{
    do_accept();
}

void chat_server::do_accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket), room_)->start();
            }

            do_accept();
        });
}
```

Comment: `using namespace` should be avoided in header files, please post the full compiler error output

Comment: I can't spot a header guard in your `chat_server.h`. Do you have one, you just don't show here? If you don't, it's very likely that you'll get multiple definition errors from the linking phase.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ missing include guards generally give multiple definition errors from the compiler not the linker. As the file is only included once in each cpp file it shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oops, yes. My bad. If not proven otherwise most likely the OP's problem though.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I edited the error list in the post. I am sorry if the format isn't right.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I forgot to add the header guard but it's there in the actual code.

Comment: please show the text from the compiler output window not the error list from your IDE, it will contain more details

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, Alan. I added the output in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/pull/584

`include/boost/asio/impl/use_awaitable.hpp` has an error, `dummy_return` should be marked `inline`.

Change:

```
template <>
void dummy_return()
{
}
```

to:

```
template <>
inline void dummy_return()
{
}
```

Comment: I put `boost::asio::dummy_return` into google, it was one of the top results (actually [this](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/4008) but that links to the asio PR). Pasting error messages into google (preferably from the compiler output not the IDE error list) often yields a solution to your problem.